# Using Pandas read_table with list of files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop

I am pretty new to Python in general, but am trying to make a script that takes data from certain files in a folder and puts it into an Excel spreadsheet.

The code I have will find the file type that I want in my specified folder, and then make a list with the full file paths.

```
import os
file_paths = []

for folder, subs, files in os.walk('C://Users/Dir'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".log") or filename.endswith(".txt"):

                file_paths.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder,filename)))
```

It will also take a specific file path, pull data from the correct column, and put it into excel in the correct cells.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

for i in range(len(file_paths)):
    fields = ['RDCR']
    data = pd.read_table(file_paths[i], sep= "\s+", names = fields, usecols=[3],
```

Where I am having trouble is making the read_table iterate through my list of files and put the data into an excel sheet where every time it reads a new file it moves over one column in the spreadsheet.

Ideally, the for loop would see how long the file_paths list is, and use that as the range. It would then use the file_paths[i] to input the file names into the read_table one by one.

What happens is that it finds the length of file_paths, and instead of iterating through the files in it one by one, it just inputs the data from the last file on the list.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate all of them at once and write to excel one time.

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob('C://Users/Dir/*.log') + glob('C://Users/Dir/*.txt')

def read_file(f):
    fields = ['RDCR']
    return pd.read_table(
        f, sep="\s+",
        names=fields, usecols=[3])

df = pd.concat([read_file(f) for f in files], axis=1).to_excel('out.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I modified things a bit with the code you have and it's much cleaner!

Comment: Then final question: the files I'm importing data from sometimes have the numeric table start on different rows. Is there any way to tell python to start the column at the first row with a number instead of a specific row? That way it can account for variations in the position of the data I want.

Comment: @JohnZilverberg I'd suggest asking a different question.  That would be useful to answer separately.